# Post status update with location

Tags: facebook-graph-api, location, coordinates, latitude-longitude

When you post a regular status update to Facebook, it tracks your current location and gives the (near) city next to the time. I.e.: May 24 near *New York City, New York*. Please note that this is **not** a check-in.

I'm trying to do the same, without searching for a page (place) id and checkin.
I've tried posting the [coordinates with latitute and longitute](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=POST&path=me/feed&message=test&coordinates=%7B%22latitude%22%3a%2037.4163458217,%22longitude%22%3a%20-122.15198690595%7D), but it doesn't show the near city.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed

message=test
coordinates={"latitude": 37.4163458217, "longitude": -122.15198690595}
```

Answer (score 0):

please check this url 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/status/

you have to pass the coordinates as an object called place , and that will have the details about the place , few more details about place object ...

```
object containing id and name of Page associated with this location, and a location field containing geographic information such as latitude, longitude, country, and other fields (fields will vary based on geography and availability of information)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Raquibul!

But I don't get it to work, I've tried it like this (as PHP-array):

`array
 (
  "message" => "My message",
  "place" => array
   (
    "location" => array
     (
      "latitude" => 40.714353,
      "longitude" => -74.005973,
      "country" => "US"
     )
   )
 );`

It gives an error, but nothing specific. The documentation really fails on this part, no example, nothing...

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an old question, but just to confirm, posting via an app can only let you tag a place using the place ID.
Please check these related posts -
https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/03/07/building-better-stories-with-location-and-friends/ 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/actions/#taggingplaces