# Facebook API: how to post status update with location (latitude + longitude)?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, location

Need to post status update and attach user location by passing latitude and longitude. In [FB docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/) they say, we need to pass "place" FB entity that is:

*"an object containing id and name of Page associated with this location, and a location field containing geographic information such as latitude, longitude, country, and other fields (fields will vary based on geography and availability of information)"*

How to create/get such place name from latitude and longitude? I'v read related [post1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10871517/post-status-update-with-location) and [post2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8244603/is-it-possible-to-create-a-facebook-place-through-the-graph-api) but was not able to find a working solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How to create/get such place name from latitude and longitude?

There is currently no API available for developers to **create** Facebook pages or places. However, you can **get** place name by doing a FQL query like this...

```
'SELECT page_id,name,latitude,longitude FROM place WHERE distance(latitude, longitude, "LAT_HERE", "LON_HERE") < 250`
```

`250` refers to the radius(m) that it will search within, it can go up to `50000`.

Doing this FQL query will return you the Facebook Place Page's id, **place name**, latitude and longitude.

(Actually there is no need to get the place name as the `page_id` is what you really need. With `page_id`, you will be able to get all the information of that Facebook Place Page.)

> Need to post status update and attach user location by passing
>   latitude and longitude.

Assuming you are actually trying to publish a checkin, you can refer to the references below to proceed further with the data you have obtained from the FQL query...

**A normal status update(feed dialog) is different from a status update with location tagged to it(checkins), they are using different APIs**.

**References:**

[How to get place_id before checkin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11828940/how-to-get-place-id-before-checkin/11882689#11882689)

[Facebook - Publish Checkins using PHP SDK/JavaScript SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11072933/facebook-publish-checkins-using-php-sdk-javascript-sdk/11101740#11101740)

**Facebook Documentations**

Page FQL - http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/page/

Checkins API - http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#checkins

Answer (score 1):

If you have the lat/long data, you can search for the place and get the place-id which can be included in the POST message.
Please check these related posts -
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/actions/#taggingplaces 
https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/03/07/building-better-stories-with-location-and-friends/