# Post to facebook wall through graph API including Location

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to perform a post to Facebook wall through the Graph API including location coordinates?

An example through Graph API explorer will be helpful!
thanks!

Comment: No, you can only pass a _place id_ when creating a post. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#posts

Comment: This seems similar to this question: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10871517/post-status-update-with-location

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible,

you can create a post to the users wall with a location if he/she has given you the publish_stream access

look into the Graph api documentation [Facebook Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#posts)